# Running Laravel job chain synchronously

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-queue

I have a Laravel job chain like this

```
Job1::withChain([
  new Job2(),
  new Job3(),
  new Job4()
])->dispatch();
```

Sometimes I want it to run the job synchronously.

But when I change `->dispatch()` to `->dispatchNow()`, I get

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingChain::dispatchNow()

Is there any other way to run a job chain synchronously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `allOnConnection` method and run them on the `sync` connection:

```
Job1::withChain([
  new Job2(),
  new Job3(),
  new Job4()
])->dispatch()->allOnConnection('sync');
```

Just check that the `driver` for the `sync` connection in your `config/queue.php` file is indeed `'sync'`.

Another option, which is not ideal for when you want to easily "toggle" between running the jobs synchronously vs asynchronously, is to just dispatch them one after the other, e.g.:

```
Job1::dispatchNow();
Job2::dispatchNow();
Job3::dispatchNow();
Job4::dispatchNow();
```